# SSH drops a few seconds after connecting

Tags: ssh, openwrt

I have a TP-Link MR-3020 router that is hardwired to my "real" router. The TP Link has OpenWRT installed on in and has the static IP address of 192.168.1.111 assigned to it. From my laptop, I can

```
ssh root@192.168.1.111 into the router.
```

Often times it will say

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.111 port 22: Connection refused.
```

If I wait a few seconds and try again, I may get the same error or I may be prompted for the password. If I'm able to successfully log in I will often be kicked out with a broken pipe. Sometimes it's 5 seconds after logging in, sometimes it's 5 hours.

All of this is happening internally on a network and I've confirmed there aren't any other 192.168.1.111 devices out there being assigned by DHCP. What are some things I can do to debug why I keep losing my connection?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should understand if it is SSH-only issue, or your router is rebooted / goes offline completely. To do so, start `ping` and watch if it work when SSH doesn't allow you to connect.

If ping works, but SSH doesn't, then watch the *process id* of dropbear process (ssh daemon) issuing `pgrep dropbear` command. If it changes, then SSH process is restarted, and it needs further investigation.

Also, post your logs (`logread` and `dmesg` command) - it might contain useful information on this issue. Try to note the time when SSH goes off and look for corresponding lines in the log.